# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.function.Function<java.lang.String, kotlin.Unit>'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, javabeans, autowired

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    fun storeCertificate(): Function<CacheData, Unit> {
        return Function { cacheAndData ->
//CacheAndData is a data class
            val (cache, key, cert, duration) = cacheAndData
            (cache.nativeCache as? RedisCacheWriter)
                    ?.run { put(CACHE_ISSUER_KEY, key.toByteArray(), ByteUtils.getBytes(cert), duration) }
                    ?: cache.put(key, cert)
        }
    }
}
```

In service autowired
 private val storeCertificate: Function

During test run 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.function.Function' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Comment: @Service
class CertificateRevocationService(                                   private val storeCertificate: Function<CacheData, Unit>) {

Also autowiring this service in test class (All in kotlin)

Comment: Sorry for the error msg the 
right error msg is

NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.function.Function<CacheData, kotlin.Unit>'